# EKAlarm will not set in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, eventkit

I wrote the following snippet to create an event. Setting the alarm works fine in iOS 4, but in iOS 5 it doesn't get set.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
EKCalendar *cal = [self.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
event.calendar = cal;
// .......
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600];
event.alarms = [NSArray arrayWithObject:alarm];
// .......
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.

The problem seems that **startDate** shoudln't be the same as **endDate**... really silly iOS change!

Comment: whoa.. this helped me out in ios7.1 too, for reference I was getting a `NSError` with `Code=29` in `EKErrorDomain` about "unable to modify alarms" which is also not documented.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to that's happening in this ticket: [EventKit - App freezes when adding an EKEvent with 2 alarms (iOS 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844402/eventkit-app-freezes-when-adding-an-ekevent-with-2-alarms-ios-5/7880198#7880198).

If you take a look at the EventKit section in the iOS 5 changes from iOS 4.3 document, it mentions that some items are deprecated for EKEvent. The hierarchy has changed and a new abstract superclass has been added: [EKCalendarItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010882-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid manipulating the alarms array. You need to add the alarm to your event like this:

```
EKAlarm *reminder = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-300];
[event addAlarm:reminder];
```

This will add a reminder 5 minutes before the start time.