# EventKit - App freezes when adding an EKEvent with 2 alarms (iOS 5)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, eventkit

I have an app that programmatically adds reminders to your iOS device's calendar.

Previous to iOS 5, I could add a calendar item with two alarms thusly:

```
EKEventStore* eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent* event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
// set startDate, endDate, title, location, etc.

[event addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60.0f * -5.0f]]; // 5 min
[event addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60.0f * -15.0f]]; // 15 min

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError* error = nil;
BOOL success = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
```

On iOS 5 this *freezes the application*.  It does not return with an error - it just never returns.

If I only call addAlarm once, it works as expected.

On iOS 4.2, calling addAlarm twice works just fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: FYI I've submitted a bug on this to Apple; will update this post as I hear more.

Comment: Yes - it is fixed in 5.1b2 .  I've confirmed this on a friend's device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug with Apple. If you set 2 alarms it causes the app to freeze. If you only set 1 it works just fine. This is fixed in iOS 5.1 .

Answer (score 0):

have you tried calling addAlarm using a variable?

```
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60.0f * -5.0f]]; // 5 min
[event addAlarm:alarm];

EKAlarm *alarm2 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60.0f * -15.0f]]; // 15 min
[event addAlarm:alarm2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the EventKit section in the iOS 5 changes from iOS 4.3 [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html), it mentions that some items are deprecated for EKEvent. The hierarchy has changed and a new abstract superclass has been added: [EKCalendarItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010882-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3).

Comment: What he wants to do should still work though. The alarm-related methods just got moved to EKCalendarItem. Nothing alarm-related got removed or deprecated.

Comment: Exactly.  I haven't tried using the new class hierarchy as a "workaround".  If my bug report to Apple gets no traction, I'll give it a try and let you know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

The problem seems that **startDate** shoudln't be the same as **endDate**... really silly iOS change!

Comment: I ran into that as well, but even with that fixed, I CAN add a calendar item with one alarm, but it freezes if I've added two alarms.