# Adding events to calendar in ios 5 programatically

Tags: xcode, calendar, ios5

```
eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *addEvent=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
addEvent.title=@"hello";
addEvent.startDate=messageDate;
addEvent.endDate=[addEvent.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];
[addEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
addEvent.alarms=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:addEvent.startDate]];
[eventStore saveEvent:addEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:nil];
```

The code above works fine in ios 4.2 but not in ios 5. I have the code in applicationDidfinishingLaunching method. Due to error, black screen appears and app exits. Only recurrenceRules has changed in ios 5 and I have not made use of it. All other properties are available in superclass EKCalendarItem. I cannot test it since I have xcode 3.2 and snow leopard. I am looking to debug the line at which error occurs causing the app to quit. I doubt it is related to setCalendar or using alarms property.

Comment: Its working perfectly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct and works in iOS 5. The reason for my error was the first line

```
eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

Since initializing eventstore takes some time, placing it in application launch method resulted in time out. I found it from my crash report stating:

```
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds):30 seconds"
```

The app is supposed to launch within 10 seconds. if not time out occurs with `Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 5th version of SDK. You can find a diff in saveEvent function:

```
[eventStore saveEvent:addEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
```

It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

There was a change (I believe) to the API in iOS5 that requires you to add EKAlarm objects using the `addAlarm` instance method.

To add an alarm to your event in iOS5:

```
[addEvent addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:addEvent.startDate]]
```

Check [EKCalendarItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Although `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *alarms` is not specified as *read only* it would appear to be behaving that way.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880242/816455 for more information on other iOS5 EKAlarm issues.

Answer (score 0):

NaveenaRK I wasn't having any time out errors however i fixed this by doing the following.

You need to keep the eventStore in memory for the objects life time.

```
eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init]
```

I initialised the event store on creating the object and released it in dealloc. The problem with setting the alarms and the "CADObjectGetInlineStringProperty" error were both fixed.