# is it possible to change the default alarm timings in icalendar using eventkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I used the following code to display a calendar using EVENTKIT

```
    - (BOOL)createEvent:(NSString *)title 
                 at:(NSString *)location 
           starting:(NSDate *)startDate 
             ending:(NSDate *)endDate 
           withBody:(NSString *)body 

{

    eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title     = title;
    event.location  = location;
    event.startDate = startDate;
    event.endDate   = endDate;
    event.notes     = body;

    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    EKEventEditViewController *eventViewController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
    eventViewController.event = event;
    eventViewController.eventStore = eventStore;
    //eventViewController.editViewDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];

    return TRUE;
}
```

When i call this above function , an eventkit view controller is displayed.
When i click the the alert button in that, i will get the default alert timing as like below

[image: Event Alert]

I want the event alert timing in whatever way i wish like 1 day before,2 days before upto 30 days before.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Try:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13347525/1442541

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to create an EKAlarm, and add that alarm to your event.  For instance, for an alarm that occurs 15 min before:

```
    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-900]; // 15 min alarm
    [event addAlarm:alarm];
```